# Using "or" in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting error when using "or" to filter the dataframe.
Below is the code:

```
df.select("InvoiceNo","Description").where((col("InvoiceNo") !== 536365) || (col("UnitPrice") > 600))
```

I tried using "or" also but getting the same error.

```
df.select("InvoiceNo","Description").where((col("InvoiceNo") !== 536365).or(col("UnitPrice") > 600))
```

Error:

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UnitPrice' given input columns: [InvoiceNo, Description]
```

Where could have I gone wrong?
Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of [**relational algebra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra), when you perform a selection (`select`) with Spark SQL, this narrows down the columns to which you have selected.

Thus you won't be able to call on the ones you haven't selected to perform a projection (`where`,`filter`).

The logic is slightly different from the regular SQL logic so mainly in your case, you would want to do the following :

```
val df2 = df
 .where((col("InvoiceNo") !== 536365).or(col("UnitPrice") > 600)) // projection (π)
 .select("InvoiceNo","Description") // selection (σ)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only selected two columns `InvoiceNo, Description` and code is try to filter the based on the columns you have selected in which `UnitPrice` is not present.

You can try the following :

```
df.select("InvoiceNo","Description","UnitPrice").where((col("InvoiceNo") !== 536365).or(col("UnitPrice") > 600))
```

In case , you need to select specific columns, use `select` after `where`.

```
df.where((col("InvoiceNo") !== 536365).or(col("UnitPrice") > 600)).select("InvoiceNo","Description","UnitPrice")
```

Comment: This worked but my requirement is not met. The select method should be followed after where.

Comment: yeah.. if you have to select only 2 columns , then your select should follow after the where.